# Mikro-orm config with apollo server - entity manager

Tags: apollo-server, mikro-orm

I'm trying to figure out how to connect mikro-orm to psql with apollo-graphql. I'm trying to follow the lireddit tutorial by Ben Awad.

Currently, I'm stuck with the config.

This code block is offending mikro-orm principles and I can't figure out how to resolve them.

```
 const orm = await MikroORM.init<PostgreSqlDriver>(config);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

const app = express();

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema: await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver],
    validate: false
  }),
  context: () => ({ em: orm.em })
})
```

The error messages say:

> Argument of type '{ schema: any; context: () => { em: any; }; }' is
> not assignable to parameter of type 'Config'.   Type
> '{ schema: any; context: () => { em: any; }; }' is missing the
> following properties from type 'Config': logger,
> debug, cache, formatError, and 6 more.ts(2345) Argument of type '{
> resolvers: [typeof HelloResolver, typeof PostResolver]; validate:
> boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'BuildSchemaOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'validate' does not exist in type 'BuildSchemaOptions'

I tried amending the types.ts config as follows:

```
import { EntityManager } from "@mikro-orm/postgresql";

export type MyContext = {
    em:  EntityManager
}
```

This doesn't solve either problem.

There is an [example](https://github.com/driescroons/mikro-orm-graphql-example/blob/master/src/application.ts) config in the mikro-orm docs that defines the schema as follows:

```
const schema: GraphQLSchema = await buildSchema({
        resolvers: [BookResolver, AuthorResolver],
        dateScalarMode: 'isoDate',
      });
```

For that, it needs:

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
```

When I try this, I get the same error as when I try the approach Ben uses.

I have a problem using Ben's example in resolver/post.ts, as follows:

```
@Resolver()
export class PostResolver {
    @Query(() => [Post])
    posts(@Ctx() { em }: MyContext): Promise<Post[]> {
        return em.find(Post, {});
    }
}
```

> Type 'Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Post[]>'.
> Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Post[]'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Post': id, createdAt, updatedAt, title

Graphql does not recognise the post resolver at all.

Has anyone figured out how to complete the config to connect mikro-orm with psql and apollo graphql at this step (50mins into the tutorial)?

Comment: Have you seen this project? https://github.com/driescroons/mikro-orm-graphql-example

Comment: Also note that 1. the error you say is about MikroORM is not, it is about some resolvers, nothing ORM related, and 2. you should pass a fork of the EM in the context, here you are using the global EM which is just wrong and won't work with concurrent requests.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been looking through the project files showing how to implement mikro orm. I'm trying to follow the logic of this line ( context: { req, res, em: this.orm.em.fork() } as MyContext,). I'll be a while whilst I try to go down this thought process. Fingers crossed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are importing `buildSchema` from the correct package:

```
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
```

and not from :

```
import { buildSchema } from "graphql";
```